# why does the :active property not working?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors

i am doing this using bootstrap but when i apply :active state as background color its not showing it but it is changing text color
here's the HTML code :-

```
<button class="btn btn_style">1</button>
          <button class="btn btn_style">2</button>
          <button class="btn btn_style">3</button>
          <button class="btn btn_style">4</button>
          <button class="btn btn_style">5</button>
```

CSS code :-

```
.btn_style {
    background-color:   hsl(216, 12%, 8%);
    color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;
}
```

```
.btn_style:hover, .submit_btn {
    background-color: hsl(25, 97%, 53%);
    color: #fff;
}
```

```
.btn_style:active {
    border: none;
    background-color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
    color: #fff;
}
```

i want it's active state as

```
background-color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
    color: #fff
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:active` pseudo-selector is used to select links that have been clicked. What you’re looking for is `:focus`:

```css
.btn_style:focus {
  border: none;
  background-color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: what i can do to get this effect on click